# Using an objective function in Microsoft Solver Foundation Services (SFS)

Tags: c#, optimization, ms-solver-foundation

With the lower-level Solver programming (MS Solver Foundation Solvers) it is possible to assign an objective function to an optimization model, as shown below from the Rosenbrock sample:

```
solver.FunctionEvaluator = OriginalRosenbrockFunction;
solver.GradientEvaluator = OriginalRosenbrockGradient;
solver.Solve(solverParams);

private static double OriginalRosenbrockFunction(INonlinearModel model, int rowVid, ValuesByIndex values, bool newValues) {
double value = Math.Pow(1 - values[1], 2) + 100 * (Math.Pow(values[2] - (values[1] * values[1]), 2));
return value;
}
```

Is it possible to assign an objective function to an optimization model at the higher level, within Solver Foundation Services (SFS) programming?

I would like to stay withing the higher level SFS if it is possible to use an objective function at this level.

Comment: I usually deal with nonlinear optimization problems with linear constraints.

Comment: I found a possible answer to my question here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4bb43c28-f233-4869-87ee-8a8e3ad0dc06/extremum-for-an-arbitrary-nonlinear-function-or-a-class-method-with-microsoftsolverfoundation-c?forum=solverfoundation